# Getting "Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character" while getting JSON with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I've spent the last few days trying to get around this problem. Every time I try to get a JSON object using Angular's $http.get, I get "Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character".

My JSON is created using the PHP's json_encode. The PHP code is the following:

```
header('Content-Type:application/json');
echo json_encode($to_encode);
```

The JSON it creates looks like this:

```
{"id":"1","para":{"para_id":"1","story_id":"1","para_content":"&quot;\u017bagiel na horyzoncie!&quot; - s\u0142ycha\u0107 krzyk z bocianiego gniazda. Fregata Jego Kr\u00f3lewskiej Mo\u015bci &quot;Acanta&quot; \u017cwawo sunie przez b\u0142\u0119kit oceanu. Ty, jej dow\u00f3dca, stoisz na rufie. Bosman i sternik patrz\u0105 si\u0119 na ciebie, oczekuj\u0105c rozkaz\u00f3w."},"tunnels":[{"tunnel_id":"1","start_para_id":"1","end_para_id":"2","tunnel_content":"Spokojnie, zbli\u017cmy si\u0119 i sprawd\u017amy, kto to."},{"tunnel_id":"2","start_para_id":"1","end_para_id":"3","tunnel_content":"Bi\u0107 na alarm! Za\u0142oga do dzia\u0142!"}]}
```

(It's UTF8-encoded Polish, if it's relevant; the text is just a placeholder)

The JS that gets it look like this:

```
$scope.current_para = $http.get("/gamebook/run");
$scope.current_para.then(function(os){result = os.data; console.log(result);}
```

Instead of a neat JSON in my console.log, I get the error, even though my Firebug tells me that the GET method was successful and even shows me the JSON it received.

Comment: Does it work without the Polish language parts? I know this won't resolve your problem but it'll be good to know if it's one of those Polish characters causing the problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976476/latin1-utf-8-encoding-problems-in-angularjs Maybe that will do it?  Just a guess.

Comment: If it's encoded in UTF-8, then why does it include escaped Unicode code points?

Comment: No, it doesn't even after removing all Polish chars. It was the first thing I've checked, since Polish special chars are the most common reason for erros in my job.

Comment: @Tim Withers: I'm afraid it won't do - the problem is not with sending JSON to server, but with receiving data. :/

Comment: @superEb: To tell the truth, I have no idea. It's what the json_encode does and since I have little experience in JS, I just figured it was some norm.

Comment: The JSON itself is okay. Double check if the proper data are sent from server -- especially check if the route of GET request is handled properly at server side. (in my case, exception like yours almost always means, that wrong file has been sent eg. some html view instead of json data)

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a workaround to this problems - I still don't know what or why happened, but here's what could be done.

On the server side you have to wrap your JSON data in single quotes (making it a string) then use eval() in JS to turn it back into JSON.

I know it's not elegant, but that's the only solution I've found. Hope it'll help someone.

Thanks everyone for the input!